# expected primary-expression before '->' token

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

**HOW CAN I RESOLVE IT PLEASE? IM TRYING TO DO THIS FUNCTION BY REFERENCE**

```
int inserir_hospede(hospede *AddHos)
{
    FILE *cadastros_h;

    cadastros_h = fopen("Hospedes.dat","a");

    imprime_cabecalho();
    printf("INSERINDO CADASTRO\n\n");

    printf("Nome: ");
    gets(-> *AddHos.nome);

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("RG: ");
    gets(-> AddHos.rg);

    fflush(stdin);


    fwrite(&AddHos,sizeof(AddHos),1,cadastros_h);

    printf("\n\n\n\n\nPressione ENTER para 'SALVAR' e voltar ao menu principal.");
    getch();

    fclose(cadastros_h);
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour, `gets` shouldn't exist, and you need to research a bit, because I'm sure it's not hard to find how to use pointers to objects.

Comment: Try something simpler.

Answer (score 2):

```
gets(-> *AddHos.nome);
```

To a C compiler (or C programmer), this is ridiculous.

## `gets`

**Don't** use `gets`. It has no protection against buffer overflows (potential segmentation fault, potential security vulnerability). Use `fgets(str, /* length of str */, stdin)` instead.

## `->`

This is not any sort of assignment operator; it is the indirect member access operator. `ptr->foo` == `(*ptr).foo`. (`gets` doesn't treat it specially, either; `gets` is a normal function.)

## `fflush(stdin)`

`fflush` only works on output streams. **It has undefined behaviour on input streams**. Some implementations might give it semantics on input streams, but this is **very very non-portable.** Just don't do it.

## Repairs

The line of code at the start of my post could perhaps be better written as

```
fgets(AddHos->nome, sizeof(AddHos->nome), stdin); // assumes nome is a char[]
```

The other `gets` could be reworked as

```
scanf("%d", &AddHos->rg); // assumes rg is an int
```

`scanf` is often the wrong tool for the job, and even here (where it isn't) it will need some supporting code; but that should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

To give a clear answer, could you please define "hospede" here

Assuming "hospede" typedef to a structure.

For this, **gets(-> *AddHos.nome);**
Change it to: **gets(AddHos->nome);**

For this **gets(-> AddHos.rg);**
Change it to: **gets(AddHos->rg);**

Comment: That would be `fgets(AddHos->whatever, /* size of whatever */, stdin);`. Seriously, don't use `gets`.

Comment: i think he needs to get data from stdin and write that to file (using fwrite). not sure.. since code is cryptic. :)

Comment: If that was meant to be an add-on to your answer, edit it in. If it was meant to be commentary on my recommendation of `fgets`, repeat the following until it sticks: ***Don't use `gets`.***